# Is it possible to re-install Android OS When the OS is practically useless

Tags: rom-flashing

As the title suggests I'am trying to re-install Andriod but their are several criteria that are preventing me

**1.** the Android operating system boots but upon passing the lock screen, all core processes such as launcher crashes meaning i'm unable to change settings (Even though sometimes I'm able to change the settings it just reverts back upon Reboot and the settings don't even work properly)

**2.** ADB does not detect the device (assuming because of USB Debugging)

**3.** Tried Android safe-mode it does pretty much the same thing as normal mode

**4.** Tried a factory reset but it just reboots and shows the Android recovery options instead of erasing

I'am currently out of options Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want more specific advice (e.g. how to install Android on **your** phone, or how to fix whatever problem makes you want to reinstall in the first place), you'll have to [edit] your question to give more details. Reinstalling Android is quite unusual, so it may be better to ask a new question describing the original problem: there might be a better way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer is yes!

**Long answer:**

you can Flash* Android "Stock Rom" for almost any type of android devices, even if the old one isn't loading at all.

as long as the hardware doesn't have any problems

but there is some problems

**1. To find the stock Rom:**
you will find it with a little search depending on device manufacture

**2. To flash it without breaking your device:**
this process can be very risky and highly depend on device type

**3. you will lose your warranty**
safest way is to find a near service center to do it for you

but you can find very useful stuff here:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/

Comment: It seems that i'm able to find some custom roms for my ZTE T815 XDA forums But no Factory roms on the internet so far I'll try and request the boot-loader key and Rom from the manufacturer

Comment: check this one: [link](http://www.needrom.com/download/zte-t815/ ) , but be careful !! i didn't test this i just found it on google search

Comment: OK i've grabbed the Rom so how do flash the rom

BTW Do i need to unlock the Boot loader for this ?

Comment: and before you say "use Fastboot" that is not an options as ADB doesn't detect my device therefore i can't force it into Fastboot

Comment: you will not need fastboot or unlock you will only need the VCOM drivers, you can follow this tutorial [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=66221446&postcount=2) .... but be very careful as you can brick your phone easily by one simple mistake!

Comment: Dumb question but on the guide it said to only tick recovery which installed the recovery image do i tick any other options in  order to reset my OS

Comment: <UPDATE> I tried ticked all options and tried Format + Download but to no avail when i rebooted the phone the problem came back

Comment: I'm afraid that you have bigger problem now, as you shouldn't format mobile Flash memory using flash tools, as you will loose other partitions which keeps important data such as IMEI and MAC,...

Comment: NO i didn't do anything not even reset the OS it did nothing the os booted up like normal and the process kept on crashing

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that I have had many times when flashing a custom operating system. Occasionally, I've found that a full rom reset (or factory reset), which is wipe data and davlik / art cache, might fix the problem however if it doesn't, then you need to re-flash.

So I ask, are you trying to flash a custom rom onto the phone? If so, then make sure you are not trying to flash a rom designed for another phone. Make sure the rom you are flashing is considered stable, and take a look at feedback from other (especially more experienced) flashers.

If you're using the factory rom, then try and reset it. If this doesn't work, then try looking for the factory rom somewhere. For HTC phones, this comes in the form of the Rom Update Utilities (or RUU), which you can find on the HTC Website or HTCDev. For Samsung phones, you can also retrieve the factory firmwares off the Samsung websites. I have no experience with any other phones, however I expect that they would also supply their firmwares online.

Comment: No i wasn't trying to flash a Custom rom and i'm unable to do a factory reset

Comment: it just happened randomly after a reboot